# How to remove duplicates from array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

The below code shows the array of duplicate data's , But I need a Unique data's from the array.
I tried many steps, but I can't find the solution:

See the below image of the output of duplicate received

[image: See the Image of duplicate data's]

JS File

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      storage: [],

    };
    this.renderData = this.renderData.bind(this);
  }
  renderData({ item, index }) {
  const datas = Array.from(new Set(item.category)); 
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{datas}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://myjsonpage', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: 'XXXXXX',
      }),
    }).then(response => { response.json().then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.status === 1) {
            this.setState({ datas:responseData.data}) ;
        } else {
          this.setState({ storage: [] });
        }
      });});}
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.continer}>
        <View style={styles.heading}>
          <Text style={styles.font}> Most Common Categories </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <FlatList data={this.state.datas} renderItem={this.renderData} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );}}
```

Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: You can use a Set: `this.setState({datas: [...new Set(responseData.data)]})`

Comment: *I tried many steps* - such as?

Comment: provide a sample data format that you receive and also post what you have tried

Comment: @Bravo are words, not code?

Comment: There is a below code in renderData function.!!

Comment: @DevAS OP removed a comment

Comment: Thanks guys..!! I find a solution with loadus.                                                                                
     const val = responseData.data; 
            this.setState({ datas: _.uniqBy(val, 'category')} );

Comment: @NickParsons When i setState i contacting two arrays, How can I remove the duplicate? I'm trying to use new Set() but not works `this.setState(
        {
          orders: [...new Set(this.state.orders.concat(this.allOrders))],
})`

Comment: @OliverD that should work fine. Maybe try: `this.setState(currState => ({ orders: [...new Set(currState.orders.concat(this.allOrders))], }))`

Answer (score 5):

There's many ways to remove duplicates from array, Use [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove your duplicates.

```
const data = ['Renewal', 'Subscriptions', 'Subscriptions', 'Subscriptions', 'Renewal', 'Renewal']

const unique = new Set(data);

const uniqueData = [...unique]; // array
```

```js
const data = ['Renewal', 'Subscriptions', 'Subscriptions', 'Subscriptions', 'Renewal', 'Renewal']

const uniqueData = [...new Set(data)];

console.log(uniqueData);
```

```
if (responseData.status === 1) {
   this.setState({ datas: [...new Set(responseData.data)] }) ;
 } else {
   this.setState({ storage: [] });
 }
```

Comment: which one is the array ```item.category``` or ```responseData.data```?